# How to calculate from 2 tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to create query for join Table A and B with condition A.salary * B.rate

```
Table A
---------------------
customerID     salary
A1              100
A2              200
A3              300

Table B
---------------------
customerID     rate
A1              2
A2              3
A3              4
```

My expect result.

```
---------------------
 customerID     salary
 A1              200
 A2              600
 A3              1200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.customerID,
       COALESCE(t1.salary * t2.rate, 'NA') AS salary
FROM TableA t1
LEFT JOIN TableB t2
    ON t1.customerID = t2.customerID
```

I used `COALESCE` when computing the effective salaries in case either the salary amount or rate be `NULL` for any customer.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Should be t1.salary * t2.rate ?

Comment: This(`COALESCE(t1.salary * t2.rate, 'NA')`) will throw conversion error in `SQL SERVER`. Not sure about `Mysql`. `Integer` has higher precedence than `varchar` so `NA` will be converted to `Integer`

Comment: @Prdp Check the Fiddle, as it works in MySQL.  The idea here is to catch `NULL` values in _either_ the salary or rate, in one expression.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Am not talking about `NULL` values. Edited my comment with explanation. But anyhow in `Mysql` it is working +1

Comment: @Prdp I think you're worried about coalescing an int value into a `varchar`.  Yes, this would probably error out on SQL Server.  In this case, we could try `COALESCE(t1.salary * t2.rate, -1)`, with `-1` indicating a salary which could not be reported.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
select a.customerID, a.salary * b.Rate salary
from TableA a inner join TableB b
on a.customerID = b.customerID
order by a.customerID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFNULL if rate is not exist then at least it should return salary instead of zero:

```
SELECT t1.customerID,
   (t1.salary * IFNULL(t2.rate, 1)) AS salary
FROM TableA t1
LEFT JOIN TableB t2  ON t1.customerID = t2.customerID
```